# How to find minimum and maximum in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am finding maximum and minimum value from a list of key-value pairs. For this I wrote this for loop code:

```
for key, values in groups.iteritems():
    MaxY = max(values)
    print 'Maximum Value of Y ='  
    print MaxY
    MaxX = max(values)
    print 'Maximum Value of X ='  
    print MaxX
    MaxZ = max(values)
    print 'Maximum Value of Z ='  
    print MaxZ
```

I want output like this :

**Maximum Value of Y =**

**Maximum Value of X =**

**Maximum Value of Z =**

But this is printing three times like this :

```
Maximum Value of Y =..
Maximum Value of X =..
Maximum Value of Z =..
Maximum Value of Y =..
Maximum Value of X =..
Maximum Value of Z =..
Maximum Value of Y =..
Maximum Value of X =..
Maximum Value of Z =..
```

I want values in MaxX, MaxY, MaxZ for maximum values.

Comment: You are printing `max(values)` 3 times. What are `y`, `x` and `z` here? Keys in your dictionary?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data ?

Comment: These are key here...The list looks like as :
[('X', '62.811'), ('Y', '23.073'), ('Z', '231.341')...]

Comment: There can be multiple tuples with 'X' as the first element?

Comment: If your data is `[('X', '62.811'), ('Y', '23.073'), ('Z', '231.341')]`, you already know the maximum values. They're 62.811, 23.073, and 231.341. Why use `max` at all? Or is there something more to the list? If so, please provide some examples beyond the first three elements.

Comment: @Kevin: Those are strings; the maximum values are `'8'`, `'7'`, and `'4'`, respectively. :-P

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want the maximum of each string, or whether there are more tuples with the same keys and you want to find the maximum value e.g. `[('X', '62.811'), ('X', '23.073'), ('X', '231.341')] --> max_x = 231.341`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing `max(values)` **each loop iteration**, 3 times. So, for `X`, you print `max(values)` three times, then do it again for `Y`, and once more for `Z`.

Print the maximum just *once* for each iteration, and print the key instead of hardcoding it:

```
for key, values in groups.iteritems():
    valuemax = max(values)
    print 'Maximum Value of', key, '='
    print valuemax
```

In other words, leave the repetition to the loop; that's what it is there for.

If you wanted to store these maximi, use a new dictionary:

```
maximi = {}

for key, values in groups.iteritems():
    valuemax = max(values)
    print 'Maximum Value of', key, '='
    print valuemax
    maximi[key] = valuemax
```

Don't try and set new local variables based on the keys; keep your data out of your variable names.

Comment: How to store these values in MaxX, MaxY, MaxZ..??

Comment: @user3522951: You don't; you'd use a dictionary instead.

Comment: This will give an error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` for the example data posted in a comment on the question.

Comment: @Scorpion_God: no, those are strings actually.

Comment: So you will be taking the maximum of a string...?

Comment: @Scorpion_God: if the data is as it is shown in the comment, then yes, each of `values` is treated as a sequence of characters and the one with the highest byte value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution would be

```
MaxX = max(float(b) for (a, b) in groups if a == 'X')
MaxY = max(float(b) for (a, b) in groups if a == 'Y')
MaxZ = max(float(b) for (a, b) in groups if a == 'Z')
```

...but that requires iterating `groups` three items. Not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [('X', '62.811'), ('Y', '23.073'), ('Z', '231.341'), ('X', '78.351')]
dict_data = {}
for key, value in data:
    value = float(value)
    if key in dict_data:
        dict_data[key].append(value)
    else:
        dict_data[key] = [value]
max_data = {key: max(values) for key, values in dict_data.items()}

>>> max_data['X']
78.351
>>> max_data['Y']
23.073
>>> max_data['Z']
231.341
```